# JQuery printThis and Style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developping a javascript app and i want to add a Print Button that print an specific div. To do this i'm using a jQuery plugin named printThis ([github link](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis)) and i have tryed to use window.print() too.

```
$("#printbtn").click(function(ev){
        $("#dropzone").printThis();

        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
    });
```

At the menu u have buttons to change dropzone's background color, add divs ... etc

```
function putGrid(){
    $("#dropzone").css("background-image", "url("+blogUrl+"/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/gridMedium.png)");
    $("#dropzone").css("background-repeat", "repeat");
}

function resetBackground (){
    $("#dropzone").css("background", "white");
}
```

```
<div id="dropzone" style="background-image: url(http://Secret_Domain_xP.es/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/gridMedium.png); background-repeat: repeat repeat;">

    </div>
```

Well, the problem is:

css() function add an Style attribute and print only work with css files ( "blahblah.css" 
 or "`<style></style>`" ), anyone knows how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of touch css attributes directly, add a .myStyle class in your stylesheet with those css properties, and later call .addClass('myStyle') or .removeClass('myStyle') from your function, I think printthis.js imports your local css files.

My english is terrible sorry, hope you understand the concept